# How to split NSString and Rejoin it into two NSStrings?

Tags: ios, iphone, split, nsstring, dynamic-programming

I have a NSString like this one:

```
NSString* allSeats = @"1_Male,2_Female,3_Female,4_Male";
```

I want to split the `NSString` based on the keywords *_Male* & *_Female* and then make two separate strings like these:

```
NSString* maleSeats = @"1,4";
NSString* femaleSeats = @"2,3";
```

based on the contents of `allSeats` variable declared above.

How it will be possible to split `NSString` and then make 2 seperate strings?

Comment: Read the documentation, then write code.  Simple.

Comment: Have you ever heard of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it yourself. There is no "all done" solution. There are a few ways to do it.

Note: I didn't try my code, I just wrote it, it may don't even compile. But the important thing is that you get the whole idea behind it.

One way could be this one:

```
NSString *maleSufffix = @"_Male";
NSString *femaleSufffix = @"_Female";
NSMutableArray *femaleSeatsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *maleSeatsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *array = [allSeats componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString *aSeat in array)
{
    if ([aSeat hasSuffix:maleSuffix])
    {
        [maleSeatsArray addObject:[aSeat stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:maleSuffix withString:@""]];
    }
    else if ([aSeat hasSuffix:femaleSuffix])
    {
        [femalSeatsArray addObject:[aSeat stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:femaleSuffix withString:@""]];
    }
     else
    {
          NSLog(@"Unknown: %@", aSeat);
    }
}
NSString *maleSeats = [maleSeatsArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSString *femaleSeats = [femaleSeatsArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Of course, you could use different methods on `array`, enumerating it, use a `NSMutableString` instead of a `NSMutableArray` (for `femaleSeatsArray` or `maleSeatsArray`, and use adequate methods then in the for loop).

Comment: no visible @interface for nSString declares the selector stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString            causing this error in if else condtion?? WHY

Comment: I'd give you the way on how to do it. This methods does not exist, it just has a little typo issue : occu*rr*ences.

Answer (score -1):

I derived an idea from Larme's Clue and it works as :

Make a method as and call it anywhere :

-(void)seperateSeat

{

```
maleSufffix = @"_Male";

femaleSufffix = @"_Female";

femaleSeatsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

maleSeatsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

array = [self.selectedPassengerSeat componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for (aSeat in array)
{
    if ([aSeat hasSuffix:maleSufffix])
    {
        aSeat = [aSeat substringToIndex:[aSeat length]-5];
        NSLog(@"%@ is value in final seats ::",aSeat );

        [maleSeatsArray addObject:aSeat];
    }
    else if ([aSeat hasSuffix:femaleSufffix])
    {
        aSeat = [aSeat substringToIndex:[aSeat length]-7];
        NSLog(@"%@ is value in final seats ::",aSeat );

        [femaleSeatsArray addObject:aSeat];
    }
}    

totalMales = [maleSeatsArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
totalFemales = [femaleSeatsArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"maleSeatsAre::::%@",totalMales);
NSLog(@"maleSeatsAre::::%@",totalFemales);
```

}